# Pointing out for direction - should I use present continuous or simple present

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

My friend was looking for a lighter and I pointed him toward a guy who had stood with a citrate (not the best example, but, hey, it is a real situation). I said "This guy smokes"while pointing my finger at that guy.

Is it correct? I am curious how about saying "this guy is smoking".

In summary, I want to learn what is the difference between using
this guy smokes
and
this guy is smoking

thanks

Comment: *I pointed him toward a guy who **was standing** with a citrate*. But I don't understand this use of "citrate" - is it maybe a misguided autocorrection of ***cigarette***? The difference between (1) *He smokes* and (2) *He is smoking* is the first tells us he habitually / regularly smokes *in a general sense* (it's something he does - by default, in the past, present, and future), whereas the second simply asserts that he is smoking *right now* (perhaps he's never smoked before, and/or never will again).

Comment: There is nothing special. Just the usual "currently in progress" = "is smoking" /general fact= "smokes".  The "pointing out direction" aspect is irrelevant.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks.